# Is reviewing project structure on topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, projects

This is mostly related to the following two questions:

1. [Web application structure review](/q/35631)

   > I'd like to have suggestions about the structure of my web
   >   application.
   >
   > **What the app does:**   My app receives files from about 800 scanners around my country and the users see the scanned pages into
   >   this web
   >   application, then they can organize the pages in groups, choose which
   >   one keep and which one discard, and insert some additional information
   >   to each group.   After this, another kind of user check what the first
   >   type of user has did and approve or discard each group of pages.
   >   After that, a procedure on another server transforms each group in PDF
   >   and TIFF multi page.
   >
   > After this little background to have an idea of what my web app does,
   >   this is how the files tree looks:
   >
   > ```
   > ajax
   > |- ajaxaction1.php
   > |- ajaxactionx.php
   >
   > cache
   > |- xxx_xxxxxxxxxxxx.gif
   >
   > css
   > |- style.min.css
   > |- font-awesome.min.css
   >
   > fonts
   > | here there are the fonts needed by font-awesome.min.css
   >
   > js
   > |-functions.min.js
   > |-main.min.js
   > |-jquery.x.x.x.min.js
   > |-jquery.x.x.x.min.map
   > |-jquery.lib1.min.js
   > |-jquery.libx.min.js
   >
   > views
   > |-features.php
   > |-features.tpl
   >
   > config.ini // DB configuration file
   > index.php // the page that is used by the application
   > init.php // read description below
   > web.config // used to restrict access to only the right files
   > ```
   >
   > **ajax:**   Folder where there are PHP scripts that are called by Ajax to perform INSERT and UPDATE queries to database.
   >
   > **cache:**   Folder where there are temporary .gif files extracted from the scanned pages sent from the scanners to my server.   These
   >   images stay here just the time needed to process them, then them are
   >   deleted.
   >
   > […]
   >
   > I'd like to have reviews about how I've organized the files
   >   and folders of my application.
2. [Shaky on QUnit folder structure](/q/25000)

   > I want to write something serious in JavaScript for the first time in
   >   my life. Knowing this, I want to do TDD and write unit tests. I have
   >   experience in JUnit, but yet, how to structure my project with QUnit
   >   (my choice of framework) remains a mystery to me.
   >
   > I'm thinking something like this:
   >
   > ```
   > my-script
   > - css
   >   - my-script.css
   > - js
   >   - lib
   >     - jquery.min.js
   > - src
   >   - my-script.js
   > - test
   >   - qunit
   >     - qunit.css
   >     - qunit.js
   >   - unit
   >     - unit-a.js
   >     - unit-b.js
   >   - index.html
   > - index.html
   > ```
   >
   > Is this bad design?
   >
   > First of all, my JavaScript will be dependent on jQuery
   >   (`js/lib/jquery.min.js`) and needs a CSS file (`css/my-script.css`) of
   >   my own design. Unit tests will be run from `test/index.html` and
   >   included from `unit`. Other files needed for the tests will have to be
   >   included from `../css`, `../js` and, of course, `../src`.
   >
   > Or should the `test` directory have its own separate libraries? Should
   >   the tests try several versions of jQuery? What if I want to test some
   >   "positional" property which requires my CSS?
   >
   > The root directory `index.html` would give me the opportunity to do
   >   some manual, functional tests, to see that the CSS renders correctly.
   >   A demo page, more or less.
   >
   > And yes, guidelines on how to structure my JS when writing TDD? Until
   >   now, I've been hacking along, but I feel I need som structure.

Question 1 was upvoted and answered, question 2 was closed. The difference is that question 1 is about reviewing an existing project structure while question 2 is about helping to find a project structure.

I agree that question 2 should be closed (I added my close vote) but should question 1 also be closed as it's technically not a code review?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that first question should be on [Programmers](http://Programmers.stackexchange.com). We should flag it and see how well our new moderator handles it.

Comment: They both should be migrated to programmers imho.

Comment: @retailcoder, don't migrate Jamal, just the question

Answer (score -3):

I really think that project or class structure should be on topic - these two things blend together and class structure is already some code.